# Parentheses in attributes

Tags: qgis

I have an attribute called catdet_sector which is of type text.
The problem is that the values ​​of this attribute appear in parentheses as shown in the attached figure.
I present a personalized form which presents the values, but when the attribute is in parentheses it does not present them.

I tried the replace function but it did not work, the problem is because of the type of object I use in the form. When I use the ratio of values ​​or value map in edit mode, the parentheses appear. On the other hand, when I use text editing the parentheses disappear and the data is displayed correctly

[image]

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, the question has nothing to do with real parenthesis! They are not really in the attribute table, they just show up. QGIS3 issue, very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The replace function works fine:

```
replace( replace( "catdet_sector" , '(', ''), ')', '')
```

Comment: I tried the replace function but it did not work, the problem is because of the type of object I use in the form. When I use the ratio of values ​​or value map in edit mode, the parentheses appear. On the other hand, when I use text editing the parentheses disappear and the data is displayed correctly.